# A real sequence with a cluster set exactly =$\{n^2: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to construct a sequence with a cluster set of the form $\{n^2: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. I had  ideas of the form $u_n= \cos(\pi\sqrt{n})$, but this seems to not work.

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the sequence 
\begin{align*}
&1\\&1,2^2+1/2\\
&1,2^2+1/3,3^2+1/3\\
&1,2^2+1/4,3^2+1/4,4^2+1/4\\
&1,2^2+1/5,3^2+1/5,4^2+1/5,5^2+1/5\\
&\dots
\end{align*}
Where you read one row at a time, so it starts $(1,1,4.5,1,4.\overline{3},9.\overline{3},\dots)$

If you understand this, try to generalize it to get a sequence which has cluster set $S$, where $S$ is *any* countable set of real numbers!